# webResponse errors on some selenium regression tests

Tags: c#, selenium

We have around 300 tests running as part of regression tests.Around 10 tests fails randomly when run on build agents.I have added the full error below.If we rerun these tests on local machine it always passing.And this error does not specify the line number on which its crashed also since it is passing on local run i can not debug and find issue
We use Selenium-C# and X unit for assert.
Just want to know anyone else had this issue.

```
System.Exception: GetData webResponse content: @{ Layout = null; } <!DOCTYPE html> <html ng-app="AngularApp"> <head> <meta charset="utf-8" /> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" /> <title>Infotools Online</title> <link href="/App/Content/LancomStrap.css?3" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> <link href="/App/Content/Style.css?3" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> <link href="/App/Content/LoginThemes.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> <link href="/App/Content/MetLifeStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=vcRecaptchaApiLoaded&render=explicit' async defer></script> <script src="/App/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script> <script src="/App/Scripts/angularRecaptcha.min.js"></script> <script src="/App/Scripts/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script> <script src="/App/Scripts/angular-animate.min.js"></script> <script src="/App/Scripts/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script> <script src="/App/Scripts/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script> <script src="/App/Scripts/angular-aria.min.js"></script> <script src="/App/Scripts/angular-messages.min.js"></script> <!-- Angular Material Library --> <script src="/App/Scripts/angular-material.min.js"></script> <script src="/App/Scripts/ngClipboard.js"></script> <script src="/App/Scripts/json-formatter.js"></script> <script src="/App/Scripts/LancomStrap.js"></script> <script src="/App/Scripts/AngularController.js"></script> <script src="/App/Scripts/Chart.min.js"></script> <script src="/App/Scripts/angular-chart.min.js"></script> <script src="/App/Scripts/LoginTheme.js"></script> <script src="/App/Scripts/Federation Config.js"></script> <script src="/App/Main/LoginController.js"></script> <script src="/App/Main/AdminController.js"></script> <script src="/App/Main/ConsolesController.js"></script> <script src="/App/Main/Shares/ShareController.js"></script> <script src="/App/Main/Admin/LoggingController.js"></script> <script src="/App/Main/Admin/LogViewerController.js"></script> <script src="/App/Main/Admin/UsersController.js"></script> <script src="/App/Main/Admin/CurrentUsersController.js"></script> <script src="/App/Main/Admin/CompaniesController.js"></script> <script src="/App/Main/Admin/AdministratorsController.js"></script> <script src="/App/Main/Admin/RolesController.js"></script> <script src="/App/Admin/Admin/IHConsolesController.js"></script> <script src="/App/Main/Admin/Administrators/AdministratorController.js"></script> <script src="/App/Main/Admin/Users/UserController.js"></script> <script src="/App/Main/Admin/Companies/CompanyController.js"></script> <script src="/App/Main/Admin/Companies/Groups/GroupController.js"></script> <script src="/App/Main/Admin/Companies/Consoles/ConsoleController.js"></script> <script src="/App/Main/Components/HelperService.js"></script> <script src="/App/Main/Components/FileExplorer/FileExplorerDirective.js"></script> <script src="/App/Main/Login/TermsAndConditionsController.js"></script> <!--[if lt IE 9]> <script type="text/javascript"> inIE89 = true; </script> <![endif]--> </head> <body ng-controller="AngularParentController" ng-class="ParentSettings.Parameters.CustomTheme?'':'user_' + ParentSettings.CurrentUser.Role"> <div ng-controller="AngularController" style="z-index: 3;"> <div ng-if="ParentSettings.Location != null && ParentSettings.Location.indexOf('Admin') == 0" ng-include="'AdminMenu.html?' + ParentSettings.Random" class="cell_xs_4 cell_sm_2" style="height: 100%;"></div> <!-- SHARES PAGE -> DON'T USE DEFA
```